# Loss stuck and accuracy below 0.01 even after tweaking the dense, activation and number of layers

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, jupyter-notebook

As stated in title, I dont know how to build the optimal model for dog species recognition.

I've tried various methods such as removing layer, changing the value of dense, adding learning rate, adding decay rate, even changing optimizer but to no avail

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

#print(X)
# print(y)
model = Sequential()

# METHOD TWO(Works but not accurate, built by self)
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(2048))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(2048))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(2048))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Activation("softmax"))
model.add(Dense(120))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(optimizer = opt,
             loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])

# from tfkeras.utils import to_categorical
# y_binary = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y)
# y_binary = to_categorical(y)

model.fit(X, y,epochs=2)

Epoch 1/2
20580/20580 [==============================] - 311s 15ms/sample - loss: 4.8735 - acc: 0.0084

Epoch 2/2
12448/20580 [=================>............] - ETA: 2:02 - loss: 4.7875 - acc: 0.0071
```

Comment: You are training for only two epochs, you need to train it for a lot longer (say 50 epochs)

Comment: (from @ashish-ucsb) Can you please provide more details ? Maybe some sample images ? No. of classes ? Have you tried testing your data on popular image classification models like VGG16 or ResNet? Or have you tried testing MNIST or Cifar10 data on your model, to check if it's picking up patterns ? And also, try running it on more epochs. Please update your question with few more details.

Comment: Hi @Alexis, the dataset is from kaggle, stanford dogs dataset, and there are 120 different classes. I have not tried using VGG16/ResNet as I just want to try building my own model. I'll try running more epochs, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is few things that are wrong here :

- First activate your conv2d layer before maxpooling them ! ->

```py
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:], activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
```

or

```py
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
```

- Second, you need to do your softmax activation after your last layer not before ! Softmax is used to compute a probability for each neuron of your last layer, you need to this :

```py
model.add(Dense(120))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

- Third, like Matias said, 2 epochs is not enough at all, try to increase this number !
- Fourth, 2 conv layer for this kind of classification is not enough at all, increase this too, and variate the number of filters in order to capture differents features on the image
  A common convolutional bloc architecture can looks like this :

```py
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3) , padding='SAME'))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3) , padding='SAME'))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
```

You can manipulate this kind of block as you want, try multiple blocks with differents numbers of filters, etc

- Fifth, you have way too much neurons in your fully connected network for your problem, try a simpler architecture that will give better results in less time :

```py
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu')
model.add(Dense(128)(x)
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(120))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Tell me in the comment the results this changes gave you !

Comment: Hi @Thibault, I've made changes to my model but the loss and accurancy is still pretty bad, i've tried mnist on my model(removed conv2D) and it worked perfectly fine, i think my issue is with my conv2D, how many conv layers do you recommend? i've tried 4 but the result was the same and. I've tried having 64 filters for 2 conv layers and 128 for another 2 conv layers. The model training time is also slow as it takes about 3 minute per epochs.